# R: How do you loop an linear model over a list of data frames?

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I have a list of data frames called `AllFramesCoeff`. I want to generate a random number, have my list of data frames reference that number to refer to a random data frame and use a for loop over one of the 185 data frames in the list for two specific columns with an `lm` model. I want it to do 1000 random tests.

I also want to put the lm coefficient results in an object, probably a vector.

My plan is to later go back and create histograms, distributions and maybe plugin new columns to repeat it.

What I've tried:

```
m <- matrix(0, ncol = 2)
CorrResults<- as.data.frame(m)
for (i in length(WaFramesCoeff)) function() {
  r <- sample(185, 1)
  CorrLM <-lm(  WaFramesCoeff[i]$ `Nights_&_Weekends_Min_Used`    ~  WaFramesCoeff[i]$ `Taxes,_Surcharges_and_Fees`    ,data=WaFramesCoeff[i]  )
  CorrResults[i,]<- CorrLM$Coeff
}
```

and then:

```
m <- matrix(0, ncol = 2)
CorrResults<- as.data.frame(m)

for (i in length(WaFramesCoeff)) {
  r <- sample(185, 1)
  function(x){
  CorrLM <-lm(  x$ `Nights_&_Weekends_Min_Used`    ~  x$ `Taxes,_Surcharges_and_Fees`    ,data=x  )
  }
  CorrResults[i,]<- CorrLM$Coeff
}
```

I know this site prefers reproducible data so I apologize for the lack of it. I and a peer could not figure this out; I'm sure it's obvious but I've exhausted all my knowledge.

**EDIT**:

I came closer. But each of the 1000 only shows me the intercept. Also plot shows only a point so I obviously did not do this right.

```
CorrResults <- matrix(0, 1,1000)

    for (i in 1:1000)  {
      d <- sample(WaFramesAll,1)
      w <- sapply(  d,  TestLM  )
      CorrResults[i]<- w
    }
```

Comment: Hello again, Kootseeahknee. Your question/code are confusing. You assign a random number to `r` and never use it. What do you mean to do with it? Based on this and your other recent questions, you really should be using `lapply` to manage/process your list of data.frames, btw.

Comment: Hello, again! Yes, that is what many people have been telling me. I'm not sure why I am stuck on for loops. I know I wasn't using it correctly. I was trying to get this to randomize a number, and have an lm model apply that in calling data frame in my list, using that randomized number to select one. I wanted it to do this 1,000 times and store the lm coefficients in a vector. I'm sorry, I know my code is confusing. By the time I get to this site, it's because I've exhausted all options and have edited it many times.

Comment: So ... you know that your resulting matrix will have 185 rows but you have no way of knowing which model drives which row, right? Is that what you want? Or do you instead want to regress all of them, but you don't want/need to know the order? Something else?

Comment: I was hoping to run this 1000 times against one of the 185 data frames, randomly each time and then store each resulting coefficient in a vector for later use.

Comment: Some thoughts: remove `x$` from your call to `lm`, that's covered by `data=x`; you complain about *"only a point"*, so why then do you pre-define a matrix with only one column? You should be getting intercept and slope, so perhaps `matrix(nr=1000,nc=2)`, and then `CorrResults[i,] <- w` (but I have no idea what `TestLM` looks like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through a different way to imagine doing this kind of thing.

First, know that `for` loops have their place, and when done properly they can be just as fast as an `*apply` function. Though your use of the loop is syntactically correct, there are different ways to use it that may make more sense. You are trying to run a series of commands or a function on multiple elements of a list. Imagine this simple plan: for each element in the list, take the first element and then double and square it:

```
invec <- list(c(21,22),c(23,24),c(25,26))
str(invec)
# List of 3
#  $ : num [1:2] 21 22
#  $ : num [1:2] 23 24
#  $ : num [1:2] 25 26
outvec <- replicate(length(invec), NULL) # preallocate same size
for (i in seq_along(invec)) {
  outvec[[i]] <- c(2*invec[[i]][1], invec[[i]][1]^2)
}
str(outvec)
# List of 3
#  $ : num [1:2] 42 441
#  $ : num [1:2] 46 529
#  $ : num [1:2] 50 625
```

Seems simple enough. Now let's see how to do this same thing with an `*apply` function:

```
invec <- list(c(21,22),c(23,24),c(25,26))
outvec <- lapply(invec, function(a) c(2*a[1], a[1]^2))
str(outvec)
# List of 3
#  $ : num [1:2] 42 441
#  $ : num [1:2] 46 529
#  $ : num [1:2] 50 625
```

The way to read the apply function is *"take the vector `invec`, and call this function on each element, capturing the results into a list names `outvec`"*. The function can be "anonymous" (like it is here), or it can be a "named" function, such as

```
lapply(invec, max)
# [[1]]
# [1] 22
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 24
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 26
```

So how does this help your sampling problem? Let me diverge for another second.

Are you aware than you can index a vector and list arbitrarily? For instance:

```
str(invec[c(1,3,2,3,2,3)])
# List of 6
#  $ : num [1:2] 21 22
#  $ : num [1:2] 25 26
#  $ : num [1:2] 23 24
#  $ : num [1:2] 25 26
#  $ : num [1:2] 23 24
#  $ : num [1:2] 25 26
```

There are dupes, okay. Let's say we want to grab 1000 random samples from this very short list:

```
set.seed(3)
ind <- sample(length(invec), size=1000, replace=TRUE)
str(outvec[1:4])
# List of 4
#  $ : num 42
#  $ : num 46
#  $ : num 50
#  $ : num 46
outvec <- lapply(invec[ind], function(a) 2*a[1])
str(outvec[1:4])
# List of 4
#  $ : num 42
#  $ : num 50
#  $ : num 46
#  $ : num 42
```

Okay, so we've sampled the original list 1000 times and done our processing of it (`2*a[1]`), and stored the results.

So let's apply this to your scenario. Since your data is sight-unseen, I'll make up some.

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 20
lst <- lapply(1:185, function(ign) data.frame(x=sample(100,size=n), y=sample(100,size=n)))

str(lst[1:2])
# List of 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x: int [1:20] 19 70 57 17 91 90 13 78 44 51 ...
#   ..$ y: int [1:20] 67 39 83 15 34 47 97 96 89 13 ...
#  $ :'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ x: int [1:20] 99 30 12 16 91 76 92 33 47 74 ...
#   ..$ y: int [1:20] 78 88 62 26 83 42 37 43 21 7 ...
```

Now I have a list of 185 data.frames, each with the same two variables `x` and `y`. Let's apply your question to this data. Oh, and randomness can be time-consuming. (BTW: it is *much* faster to get 1000 random numbers once then 1 random number 1000 times.)

```
ind <- sample(185, size=1000, replace=TRUE)
```

Now, `lst[ind]` will be a list, 1000 elements long, each a random selection from the original list.

```
lms <- lapply(lst[ind], function(a) lm(y~x, data=a))
```

(The `lm` part can be whatever you need, as long as it is the same regression applied to all elements. The code in the function can be as long as you need, so perhaps think of it this way:

```
lms <- lapply(lst[ind], function(a) {
  z <- lm(y~x, data=a)
  return(z)
})
```

Does that make sense?) Okay, let's look at some of the output:

```
summary(lms[[1]])
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = a)
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -53.944 -13.463  -1.239  15.473  44.430 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  80.4523    15.3577   5.239 5.56e-05 ***
# x            -0.4217     0.2499  -1.687    0.109    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# Residual standard error: 25.23 on 18 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.1366,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.0886 
# F-statistic: 2.847 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.1088
summary(lms[[2]])
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = a)
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -55.108 -20.653  -0.465  18.827  42.747 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  60.7651    12.2366   4.966    1e-04 ***
# x            -0.1898     0.2060  -0.922    0.369    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# Residual standard error: 27.37 on 18 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.04506, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.007996 
# F-statistic: 0.8493 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.3689
```

*"But I don't need the whole model, I just want the coefficients!"* Sure, you're right. When you know you only need one thing, you can obviously just cut-to-the-chase and get that directly (such as `coef(lm(y~x,data=a))`). So, instead of me re-running the 1000 regressions of random samples, I can just do another `lapply`:

```
coefs <- lapply(lms[1:3], coef)
str(coefs[1:3])
# List of 3
#  $ : Named num [1:2] 80.452 -0.422
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x"
#  $ : Named num [1:2] 60.77 -0.19
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x"
#  $ : Named num [1:2] 53.716 -0.189
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x"
```

In this case, I actually have a couple of options. I can either stick with this and "rbind" (row-bind) them together, with

```
head(do.call(rbind, coefs))
#      (Intercept)           x
# [1,]    80.45230 -0.42173749
# [2,]    60.76507 -0.18979726
# [3,]    53.71643 -0.18883933
# [4,]    49.51803  0.01494021
# [5,]    49.51803  0.01494021
# [6,]    68.25463 -0.25840920
```

Or I could have used a "simple-apply" earlier that (optionally, but default yes) simplifies the results for you into a matrix or vector. If any of the returned values are of a different size than the others, it will always return a list. (Because of this, it might be more programmatically defensible to not simplify it, do some sanity checks, and then rbind them.)

```
coefs2 <- t(sapply(lms, coef))
head(coefs2)
#      (Intercept)           x
# [1,]    80.45230 -0.42173749
# [2,]    60.76507 -0.18979726
# [3,]    53.71643 -0.18883933
# [4,]    49.51803  0.01494021
# [5,]    49.51803  0.01494021
# [6,]    68.25463 -0.25840920
```

Notice that I had to `t`ranspose the output: it's a little kooky and counter-intuitive in that the output (without `t(...)`) will have 2 *rows* (one for each regression coefficient) and 1000 *columns*. So we transpose it, since I for one naturally think of it as row-per-model. This is not required if you can handle it as column-per-model.

So bottom line, your `for` loop is not syntactically wrong per se, but if you think about doing ONE thing to a vector/list of MANY things in this fashion, you will get significant speed improvements (in this case) and, arguably, once you understand it, much more readable code.

Comment: How goes it, Kootseeahknee? Is this off-the-mark, or does it provide any help?

Comment: Hello there. I apologize for the late response, I was busy wrapping up the project that this question was for. This was incredibly helpful! It did indeed answer my question but also clarified a few things going forward for other issues I ran into. I cannot thank you enough for taking the time to write all that out for me.